# In Star Trek Into Darkness, how many died from the crash in San Francisco?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness, kill-count

In the movie *Star Trek Into Darkness*, how many people were killed when the USS Vengeance crashed into San Francisco?

Comment: http://www.quora.com/How-many-people-died-when-Khans-ship-crashed-into-the-city-in-Star-Trek-Into-Darkness

Comment: That's a good find, @Richard. I take it from your lack of answer, this is one of those things which probably would not have an answer. You'd have to know the population density, the exact trajectory of Vengeance, plus how far it actually traveled to even come close to figuring it out. Too bad all of that exists only in the brain of JJ Abrams.

Comment: @Paulster2 - Yup. You might find something in the supplementary materials but there's no specific numbers in the novelisations or comics.

Comment: Have you considered personal emergency transporters in each building and in the area that remove thousands of people from danger to a evac location?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### "Numerous"

> As if by a giant hand, the ancient monument that was the prison on the
>   island of Alcatraz was scraped clean from its rocky promontory. The
>   collision was just enough to critically slow the vessel’s descent and
>   alter its intended trajectory. Instead of smashing into and through
>   Starfleet headquarters, it plunged into the bay.
>
> Its momentum, however, was sufficient to send it through the water and
>   slashing into the city bayfront. Tower after tower succumbed to the
>   sickening impact, crumbling before the on-rushing mass, until the
>   wreck of what had not long ago been the most powerful vessel in
>   Starfleet’s arsenal finally came to a grinding, groaning halt.
>
> The concomitant wave that rose out of the harbor swept across the
>   low-lying harbor front, inundating facilities, smashing apart
>   landscaping, and tossing vehicles about like toys.
>
> Caught in the surge, stunned onlookers struggled to stay afloat. Those
>   who managed to ride out the wave or reach higher ground fought to save
>   those who could not do so on their own. In guiding the crippled ship
>   to its end, Khan’s suicidal act gave rise to a thousand acts of
>   bravery.
>
> **There were numerous injuries and unavoidable deaths,** but the greater
>   carnage he had hoped to inflict did not occur. The slightest of
>   maladjustments that had affected the intended course of the warship’s
>   death dive meant that many more survived who would otherwise have
>   perished. <sub>[Star Trek Into Darkness : Official Novelisation](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Into_Darkness_%28novel%29)</sub>

Comment: Thanks Richard for the answer , Quara.com is also a nice one

Comment: @Bigben59 - Yes, alas it's all unfounded guesswork. Aside from the few dozen people we see in the foreground who almost definitely died, the actual numbers could be anything between a few hundred and a few hundred thousand casualties.

Comment: “As if by a giant hand” — possibly even a giant green space hand.